# Corrupt video display on D630 laptop

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a D630 laptop with an Intel GM965 video card running at 1440x900 resolution. I'm finding the display gets all messed up after half an hour or so of running, with text unreadable and lots of artifacts across the screen.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

I've tried installing the Intel Graphics Installer for linux but unfortunately they already dropped support for 14.04 and I'm not sure that will resolve the issue; Ubuntu I believe already ships with Intel drivers. Many thanks

```
 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Latitude D630
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f6e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at efe8 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: I just want to throw it out there that one of my D630's has this exact problem. The other is fine... I suspect that the bad one overheated severely at some point and that's what caused this. I have no proof of that, though - but as I experiment I will tell you what I find. And yes, Ubuntu and basically every linux distribution ever has the intel drivers pre-installed, they are included in the kernel. Can you attach a photo? next time it happens I'll do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Wyatt8740 - don't seem to have the  mod points to attach a photo. My D630, like most of my laptops at some point, occassionally failed to standby properly and would get cooked in my bag, so possibly the same issue. However, didn't experience this under Windows, and seems to only happen after running for some minutes/hours.

Comment: Hi, I have now experienced this on my other D630 and have the exact same symptoms. I'll try to get a pic to you.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ASkxjP7.png there you go.

Comment: Looks similar mate, mine was even worse. My solution was the rubbish bin, sorry I can't be more help. I guess there may be some sort of memory corruption happening at the driver level? Thanks anyay, let's see if somefind else finds this thread and has an answer...

Comment: I've had it worse than this before, too. this is just what I happened to get a photo of. Since it's linux specific, I'd have tried updating my kernel. And I wish you'd have given me that laptop... they are (mostly) awesome computers. Once my cellular data for the month rolls over, I am planning to download a newer linux kernel and see if that fixes things. :)

Comment: Just an update for anyone interested: i finally have enough free space and good internet so I'll be trying a new kernel. I'll report back if it doesn't work. Might if it does work, but I'm less likely to remember :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran to a similar screen corruption issue on Ubuntu 14.04.2 on a ThinkPad X61s which has the same graphics chipset, and found a solution. It seems that recent Intel drivers have changed from UXA acceleration to SNA acceleration by default. However, the SNA method does not always work properly with old cards, so using the older UXA is a more solid option.

Try creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
EndSection
```

Then log out (to restart the X server) and log in.

Comment: that's a great piece of research, how did you figure it out @jusic?

Comment: I kind of want to try this but I'm worried about performance penalties. Reading suggests that UXA is slower. Also is SNA actually being used here? These chipsets predate Sandy Bridge/Intel HD.